# How to SSH a UCS file on f5 device to a server

Tags: ansible, yaml, f5, ansible-awx, big-ip

I am trying to write a yaml file for ansible to take an f5 devices UCS file and send it to a server to be stored. I can't find much documentation on this and I am very new to ansible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I reckon I would use the fetch module to pull the file to my control server.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html

Then I would use the copy module to push it to the desired destination. Of course you need to make sure the account you use to SSH to your F5 device is configured to use the advanced shell. Use remote_user to specify the user for the fetch task.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html